# Hide Image Control in Gridview when no image exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I have an issue that is beginning to frustrate me. I have created a very simple blog using gridviews. I was given another requirement of being able to upload an image to posts. The issue that I am having is that if the user creates a post that doesn't have a picture, the Image Control shows anyways with the red x in it. I have tried multiple things with no success. I'm using a custom handler to get the images for the posts.

**ImageHandler.ashx**

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dboBlog"].ConnectionString);
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string messageid = context.Request.QueryString["mid"];

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Image from BlogImages WHERE Image IS NOT NULL AND MessageID=" + messageid, conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

            dr.Read()
            context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);
            conn.Close();
            context.Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

I do have an Images Table that relates to the Post table. As you can see, it uses a QueryString and retrieves the MessageID or the Posts id and then displays the image.

This is what I currently have in the Posts.aspx for the image control.

**ASP**

```
<asp:Image ID="postImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?mid="+ Eval("MessageID") %>' Width="300px" Height="300px" GenerateEmptyAlternateText="True" />
```

I have tried the solutions [here](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/886153-hide-image-if-imageurl-blank) and also the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606612/how-can-i-check-if-image-exists-in-image-control-which-is-using-handler-to-displ) but nothing has been successful for me. I have tried using the Visible property and only displaying the images that aren't "null" but same results. If anything else is needed from me, let me know!

EDIT: This is now what I have for the ImageHandler.ashx

**ImageHandler.ashx**

```
// 1x1 transparent GIF
        private readonly byte[] GifData =
        {
            0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61,
            0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x80, 0xff,
            0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x2c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
            0x02, 0x44, 0x01, 0x00, 0x3b
        };
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dboBlog"].ConnectionString);
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string messageid = context.Request.QueryString["mid"];

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Image from BlogImages WHERE Image IS NOT NULL AND MessageID=" + messageid, conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);
                conn.Close();
                context.Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
                context.Response.Buffer = false;
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(GifData, 0, GifData.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

I did update this provided by the answer given by Win. The only issue with this is that the gridview does have a styling that each row is alternating colors between White and then Grey. So there is a white box that shows up if no image and is in a grey colored row.

Comment: With the previous solutions you mention, have you tried setting the "Enabled" property to false?

Comment: On the Image Control? I have looked into it before but I think only EnableTheming and EnableViewState are the only enabling options.

Comment: Yes, I have posted it as an answer. I think this may work for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out a solution. I only save a single Image to the Table. On the insert, it either inserts the image or it inserts a "NULL" if no image was inserted. I then check to see if the table has null images, and if it does, then I disable the Image Control. I place the following in the Page_Load.

**C# Code Behind**

```
if (Page.IsPostBack || !Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow allrows in gvPosts.Rows)
                {
                    string messageid = ((Label)allrows.FindControl("lblMessageID")).Text;
                    Image image = ((Image)allrows.FindControl("postImage"));

                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand checkNullImage = new SqlCommand("SELECT Image FROM BlogMessages WHERE MessageID=" + messageid, conn);
                nullImage = Convert.ToString(checkNullImage.ExecuteScalar());

                if (nullImage == DBNull.Value.ToString())
                {
                    image.Visible = false;
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
```

Is this the best way of doing it? I'm not sure but it works and since I'm only displaying 10 Posts at a time, it works quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You can render a transparent image form image handler if no image is available.

Here is the sample -

```
// 1x1 transparent GIF
private readonly byte[] GifData =
{
    0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61,
    0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x80, 0xff,
    0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x2c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
    0x02, 0x44, 0x01, 0x00, 0x3b
};

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
        context.Response.Buffer = false;
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(GifData, 0, GifData.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works pretty good. Only issue is that in the gridview, the rows are alternating. White, Grey, White, Grey. So when a new post is added, a white square is shown in the grey.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding previous solutions you linked to, try setting the Enabled property of the image control to "false".

[Image.Enabled Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.enabled.aspx)

Comment: I'm unable to get that solution to work. I'm getting a 'ProjectName.ClassName.Enabled':no suitable method found to override @ [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
public override bool Enabled { get; set; }

Comment: Is the image control in some kind of container? If so, and you are setting the Enabled property in code, try using the FindControl() method. Hard to say without seeing how you're setting the Enabled property...